# What does this sentence mean? "The British imputed motives of piracy to American ships ..."

Tags: meaning

Here's an example sentence of word 'impute' from Merriam's Webster's Vocabulary builder.

> The British imputed motives of piracy to American ships trying to prevent them from interfering with American trade during the War of 1812.

Q1. I assume 'them' means 'the British', am I right?
Q2. So it means The British had done piracy to America or some other countries?
Q3. Then, British wanted to attribute their actions to American ships as an excuse?

Well, I don't know what this sentence actually means. Please help me. I'm learning English as a second Language.

Comment: The actual *words* are ambiguous, in that ***them*** could refer to either "the British" *or* "American ships". So this isn't a question that can be resolved by knowing English sufficiently well. You should consult some *other* source to determine which interpretation corresponds to the actual situation at the time.

Comment: Logic will see you through. The British imputed motives of piracy to American ships for a reason. This would be something that the American ships were doing. Trying to prevent _someone? who?_ from interfering with American trade. Since it is improbable that American ships would need to prevent themselves from interfering with American trade. it follows that 'them' refers to the British.

Answer (score 5):

1. Yes, in this case "them" refers to the British. As often happens, grammatically it can be ambiguous: "them" could refer to "the British" or to "American ships". Sometimes you have to think about the logic of the sentence, what would make sense in context.
2. To "impute" means to assign responsibility or blame for something. Like, "The judge imputed the fault for the accident to Jones" means that the judge blamed Jones. Tax accountants sometimes talk about "imputed income", meaning income that you didn't actually receive in cash but that tax law considers you to have received. (So you have to pay taxes on it even though you never actually got any money.)

In this case, the British were trying to block trade going to or from America during the war of 1812. If an American ship tried to fight back when the British tried to intercept them, they accused the Americans of piracy.

There's no indication in this sentence that the British were guilty of piracy. To "impute" is not necessarily to accuse someone else of something that you are guilty of. It COULD be, but the word doesn't imply that.

Comment: Wow, how awesome! I really appreciate your conscientious answer. Thank you so much! I mean really so much.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, “them” refers to the British. The Americans would not have been trying to interfere with American trade.

The sentence, **without additional context**, does not make much sense. “Impute” here means “attribute” or “assert.” That is, the obvious meaning is

> The British attributed motives of piracy to Americans who were trying to protect American trade.

If you know much about the history of that time, that meaning is odd. American privateers were admittedly a major problem to the British. But privateering was a legal mode of warfare in the early 19th century. So, it seems difficult to credit that the British would equate privateering and piracy. Of course, they could always have made propaganda claims about American piracy.

Perhaps more context would make the intended meaning clearer.